whether aiopg supports orm frameworks such as sqlalchemy
The official handbook only has instructions for sqlalchemy core; I'm not sure if aiopg supports the ORM framework.
I checked it up, but there wasn't enough information. asyncpg is known to support orm, however I had anticipated to use libpq to access pg.

It's not really a question of whether "aiopg supports SQLAlchemy", it's a question of whether SQLAlchemy supports aiopg.
Answer: No, it does not.
